# How to decide which value a property takes in a spring bean based on a condition.

Tags: spring

Can I set the property of "contentCaptureRegEx" to a regular expression say "x" based on whether an external value of an enum such as ContentType.docType.equals("regtext") ELSE set it to y.

SO,
if(ContentType.docType.equals("regtext")) 
constructor-arg is x
else
constructor-arg is y

Answer (score 0):

You can do things like that with the [Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html).

There is a dedicated chapter for pretty much exactly what you want:

> [7.4 Expression support for defining bean definitions](http://atic.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef)